# How to redirect from one activity to another after delay

Tags: android

I am developing an android application.  In this application, I want to transition from one activity to another activity automatically after 4 seconds. I don't know how to do this without a button.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is how you can proceed:

```
int timeout = 4000; // make the activity visible for 4 seconds

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        finish();
        Intent homepage = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(homepage);
    }
}, timeout);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the code in your `oncreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Handler handler=new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
         }
    },4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Handler in you activity, like:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Then in your `onCreate()` method of activity, you can call:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(yourIntent);
            }
        }, 4000);
```